# Ценовые условия в курьерских службах

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин

Решаю задачу по ценовым условиям в магазине в Битрикс.

Есть служба доставки, в которой условие, если в корзине покупок меньше 10000 рублей, то идет наценка в 500 рублей при доставка.

При покупке в более 10000 рублей наценка 0 руб. Смотрю [курс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/store/sale/settings/delivery/sale_delivery_service_edit.php#restrict)  создание и редактирование службы доставки, нет явных описаний того, как это сделать. И вообще это можно сделать не прибегая к программированию, средствами администрирования в Битриксе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересен ответ на этот вопрос. На админке Битрикса:

```
 Маркетинг > Товарный маркетинг > Правила работы с корзиной > Правила работы с корзиной
```

И добавляем новое правило, как показано на рисунке:
[image: правила]

Более подробно о правилах, [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=5354)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать собрать логику двумя путями через админку:

1. В разделе Магазин -> Настройки -> Службы доставки -> Настраиваемые, добавить одну и ту же курьерскую службу 2 раза, только с разными параметрами: 1. если сумма меньше 10000 + цена доставки 500; 2. если сумма больше 10000 цена доставки 0.
2. В разделе Магазин -> Управление маркетингом -> Правила работы с корзиной -> Правила работы с корзиной, создать новое правило (указать все необходимые параметры) и в доп условиях можно указать для какой службы доставки.

p.s. Если нужна более развитая логика, то уже нужно писать самому автоматизированную службу.

Comment: Не, тогда дважды будет показываться курьерская служба с разными атрибутами. Решение я написал, если кому интересно.

Comment: ну так я ж два варианта и предложил, второй как раз тот, который вы написали

Comment: и на счет "дважды будет показываться курьерская служба", странно, может у вас кастомный компонент, а то не логично получается, для разных сумм должны отображаться нужные службы доставки